# What is the scope of variables in Razor MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having problems with variable scope for `myClient` in my Razor code. I am sure the solution is simple. Basically I am referencing it in a seperate `@{}` block which perhaps is causing the issue, but it seems unless I do this I get the `if..{}` code in the HTML.

```
@{
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
    {
        Int32 myId = Convert.ToInt32(item.DBID);
        var myClient = db.Client.Where(c => c.Id == myId).First();
    <td>
        <table class="inner">
        <tr><th>
            @string.Format(
                "{0} {1} {2}",
                myClient.Title,
                myClient.Initials,
                myClient.LastName)

                @{
                    if (myClient.Type!="Primary")
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink(
                            "Delete", 
                            "Delete", 
                            "ClientBackground", 
                            new { id=item.ID }, null)
                    }
                 }
            </th></tr>
        }
        <table>
```

My code cannot reference `myClient.Type`. If I remove the surrounding `@{}` then I get the c# code in the HTML.

Something simple I know, but I am failing to see it.

Any help hugely appreciated.

EDIT: Table closed off.

Comment: please, post your whole code block. where `<td>` and `<table>` are closed

Comment: Hi, I did not put it in originally as I did not think I needed it for the solution. Anyway I have now, see EDIT. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table class="inner">
              @{int i = 0;}

              @foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
                  {
                      Int32 myId = Convert.ToInt32(item.DBID);
                      var myClient = db.Client.Where(c => c.Id == myId).First();


                            <tr><td>@string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",myClient.Title,myClient.Initials,myClient.LastName)
                                    @if (myClient.Type!="Primary")
                                        {
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete","ClientBackground", new { id=item.ID },null)
                                }

                    </td></tr>
              }

</table>
```

I made many guesses about formatting. Important, I put your int assignment into it's own block. I put opening and closing `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s to match and put them outside of optional `@if blocks`. But this version will compile.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Out of interest what is the difference between @{} and @. My suspicion is that the former packages multiple lines of code. I assume one can access variable out of the @{} package. I think I found my issue was with something other than variable scope.

Comment: @SamJolly you have the right idea. single statements or multi-lines. I think your issue was more nesting braces and table tags over one another. There should be clear hierarchy of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Strange syntax here:

```
@{if (myClient.Type!="Primary")
     {
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete","ClientBackground", new { id=item.ID },null)
     }
 }
```

Why not:

```
@if (myClient.Type!="Primary")
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete","ClientBackground", new { id=item.ID },null)
}
```

**Added:**

Your updated code has invalid html markup, it should look something like:

```
<table class="inner">
@{
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
{
    Int32 myId = Convert.ToInt32(item.DBID);
    var myClient = db.Client.Where(c => c.Id == myId).First();
    <tr><th>
        @string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", myClient.Title, myClient.Initials, myClient.LastName)
        @if (myClient.Type!="Primary")
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "ClientBackground", new { id=item.ID }, null)
        }
    </th></tr>
}
</table>
```

Table was not closed and you had opened `<td>` tag

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Probably "wrong" not "strange" syntax :). See my question below about @{} versus @.